# Getting an error trying to initialize this public class variable using dirname() outside a method

Tags: php, class

Why can't I set a public member variable using a function?

```
<?

class TestClass {

    public $thisWorks = "something";

    public $currentDir = dirname( __FILE__ );

    public function TestClass()
    {
        print $this->thisWorks . "\n";
        print $this->currentDir . "\n";
    }

}

$myClass = new TestClass();

?>
```

Running it yields:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in /tmp/tmp.php on line 7
```

Comment: You cannot have expressions in the variable declarations. You can only use constant values.

Comment: @mario: That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @delnan: It's just that I like to avoid one-liners as answers; but crafted some fill text now..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot have expressions in the variable declarations. You can only use constant values. The `dirname()` may not appear in this position.

If you were to use PHP 5.3 you could use:

```
  public $currentDir = __DIR__ ;
```

Otherwise you will have to initialize `$this->currentDir` in the `__construct`or.

Answer (score 4):

As per the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php), your instance variables:

> must be able to be evaluated at
>   compile time and must not depend on
>   run-time information in order to be
>   evaluated

As such, you can't use the [dirname](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) function in the property initialisation. Therefore, simply use a [constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) to set the default value via:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->currentDir = dirname( __FILE__ );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call functions when you specify attributes.

Use this instead:

```
<?php

class TestClass{

    public $currentDir = null;

    public function TestClass()
    {
        $this->currentDir = dirname(__FILE__);
        /* the rest here */
    }
}
```

Comment: This code makes no sense at all. A public global variable? A public global function named TestClass?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to copy-paste the class definition

Comment: They've changed the constructors name to __construct :)

Comment: They haven't changed it, they just added __construct at some point (PHP5?). The name of the class as constructor still works UNLESS you are using PHP5.3.3 or higher (http://www.php.net/releases/5_3_3.php) AND your class is inside a namespace.

Comment: But they are moving away from that naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can not call functions when specifying default values for member variables.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you cannot assign instance variables using functions in a static manner. It is simply not allowed in PHP.

May I suggest you do this:

```
<?
class Foo {
    public $currentDir;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->currentDir = dirname(__FILE__);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This statement is way too broad and wrong (propably just worded carelessly, but still).

Answer (score 1):

You can't call functions to declare class variables, sadly. You could, however, assign the return value from dirname( **FILE** ) to $this->currentDir from within the constructor.

*EDIT*: Mind you: the constructor in PHP => 5 is called __construct( ), not the name of the class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this instead:

```
public $currentDir = '';

public function TestClass()
{
    $this->currentDir = dirname( __FILE__ );
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dirname` expression is causing the error you can not declare an expression as a variable there. You could do this though.

```
<?

class TestClass {

    public $thisWorks = "something";
    public $currentDir;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->currentDir = dirname( __FILE__ );
    }

    public function test()
    {
        echo $this->currentDir;
    }
}
```

Everytime you instantiate a new class the dirname will be set in the constructor. I also recommend omitting the closing php tag ?> in your files. Helps to alleviate and header sent errors

Answer (score 0):

do it in the constructor.
$this->currentDir = dirname( **FILE** );

and by the way
        print $currentDir . "\n";
use $this when calling vars in class